# Using HDMI when SDI screen is installed on a RPi 4

Tags: raspbian

Someone mentioned a beta version that lets you use a HDMI screen while the SDI touch screen is installed?  Where do I find that?  My driver for the SDI screen disables the HDMI connectors of the RPi 4.  I am looking for a solution that either drives both, SDI and HDMI screens concurrently, or where the HDMI takes precedence if it is connected to a RPi 4.  Or, at least, I‘d like some kind of configuration option to enable the HDMI while the SDI is installed.

Comment: Totally depends on the drivers you are using.  Have you checked with he display manufacture or the manual / web site for driver configuration or settings?

Answer (score 1):

Bar from my comment above - the simplest way is to configure [config.txt](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/configuration/config-txt/) using the [conditional filters](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/configuration/config-txt/conditional.md) ability of the boot process.

You need to run the `tvservice -n` command to identify the two types of monitor and then use the [EDID] filter to select the correct driver eg:

```
[EDID=VSC-TD2220]
hdmi_group=2
hdmi_mode=82

[EDID=SDIMONITOR]
driver details here
```

BE AWARE:

- THIS ONLY WORKS AT BOOT TIME
- IT NEEDS TO BE UPDATED EVERY TIME YOU CHANGE MONITOR